# Make J2ME app run in background while another app can still working

Tags: java-me, background, midp, lcdui

How can I make a J2ME application run in the background so that another app can still work?

In the `MIDlet` class I tried to set `display.setCurrent(null)`, but when I try it on my Nokia device I can't play another app, and the screen only displays an exit button!

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some phones does not support background execution of Java ME apps. Assuming your phone does have it be sue to also call MIDlet.notifyPaused. According to documentation:

`Notifies the application management software that the MIDlet does not want to be active and has entered the Paused state.`

But be aware that

`If the application pauses itself it will need to call resumeRequest to request to reenter the active state.`